# How to prevent my database from being emptied on execution

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I am building a desktop application using Java, EclipseLink (JPA) and MySql . My problem is that every time I run my program, my databases is emptied. I am not able to figure out why. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

In your `persistence.xml`, change the `eclipselink.ddl-generation` setting from `drop-and-create-tables` to `create-tables`.

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL).